# RegionMember Bug in 12.2?

Tags: bugs, regions, geometry

**Bug introduced in 12.2.0 or earlier. Fixed in 13.0.0 or earlier.**

---

There appears to be an issue with RegionMember in Mathematica 12.2 when it comes to simple polygons and points.

```
poly=Polygon[{{1220.8,1293.36},{1223.43,1135.43},{1212.37,1135.54},{1214.34,980.877},{1412.85,983.389},{1410.92,1138.27},{1396.75,1138.7},{1395.27,1230.33},{1395.81,1261.74},{1384.48,1267.41},{1379.62,1279.57},{1382.03,1291.72},{1393.39,1298.2},{1392.58,1422.18},{1375.57,1416.5},{1353.66,1418.14},{1326.93,1425.42},{1293.73,1435.97},{1264.54,1435.97},{1237.81,1429.49},{1219.17,1420.58},{1218.59,1378.55},{1218.35,1361.41},{1228.9,1348.45},{1232.94,1328.98},{1230.5,1308.75}}];
pts={{1309.22,1183.11},{1380.98,1246.29}};
Graphics[{{Opacity[0.5],poly},Point@pts}]
```

[image]

However, this:

`RegionMember[poly, pts]`

results in {False,False} even though, this:

`RegionMember[poly,{{1300,1300},{1350,1350}}]` works fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
RegionMember[DiscretizeRegion[poly], pts]
```

```
RegionMember[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@poly, pts]
```

> `{True, True}`

```
RegionMember[poly // Rationalize, pts]
```

> `{True, True}`

Comment: So what's the big picture takeaway here? Just don't ever use `RegionMember` with actual regions, instead always discretize your regions first? How could anyone ever know to do this? Is there a reason the function is called `RegionMember` when it's generally incapable of determining actual region membership?

Comment: `Rationalize` is another way.

Comment: Version 12.1 `RegionMember` gives `True`. Seems to be a bug that has been fixed in 12.1

Comment: Thank you, @cvgmt for the work-arounds, but I am with Nickolas - there appears to be a bug if this function does not recognize a simple polygon as a correct region. Daniel Huber: I am using 12.2, so if it works in 12.1, the issue must have (re)appeared recently?

Comment: An update: @cvgmt Rationalize does NOT always work - I found other examples. DiscretizeRegion worked (at least on my data).

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to have been fixed in `V13.0.0`

> [image: fixed]

Comment: Yes, I confirm that RegionMember is now working for the example I had originally provided.

Comment: @drk many thanks for letting me know :)